# Fetch properties from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to fetch two properties out of each array and then form a array out of this. I have also shown the expected output.

```
columns = [
           {Header: ƒ, Cell: ƒ, sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "firstName", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "status", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "visits", sortable: false, show: true}
          ]
```

I want the output to be

```
[{name: "firstName",show: true},{name: "status",show: true},{name:"visits", show: true}]
```

I have tried this approach of getting one field, How do I get two values and then form a new array of objects itslef.

```
 let keys = [...new Set(arr.map(arr => arr.accessor))]; // able to get one property, but need two in form of object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `Map()`:

```
columns.filter(
  col => !!col.accessor).map(
   column => ({ name: column.accessor, show: column.show })
 )
```

The filter remove columns without `accessor` property.

`Map()` returns formatted array.

```js
const columns = [
           {Header:"ƒ", Cell: "ƒ", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: "ƒ", accessor: "firstName", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: "ƒ", accessor: "status", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: "ƒ", accessor: "visits", sortable: false, show: true}
          ]

const newColumns = columns.filter(
      col => !!col.accessor).map(
       column => ({ name: column.accessor, show: column.show })
     );
     
console.log(newColumns);
```

Comment: this is to make sure and evident that's casted as boolean, this is a common practice

Comment: It would still work without casting to boolean. The value only needs to be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: The cast to boolean with *doubel not operator* is for readability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to create a one-liner:

```js
const columns = [{Header:"ƒ", Cell: "ƒ", sortable: false, show: true},{Header: "ƒ", accessor: "firstName", sortable: false, show: true},{Header: "ƒ", accessor: "status", sortable: false, show: true},{Header: "ƒ", accessor: "visits", sortable: false, show: true}]

var filtered = columns.reduce((acc, {accessor:a, show}) => a ? [...acc, {name: a, show}] : acc , [])
console.log(filtered)
```

`a ?` will make a check to see if `accessor` exists, and will push the new object if it does, or return the `acc`umulator if is doesn't.

Comment: Doesn't your code break if `show` property is missing? I am not down voting because I understand that it is okay to not solve completely. You just need to unblock and show a direction

Comment: @Aditya Yes it will break, but that does not seem to be an edge case from the data OP has provided. All of the values have `show`. If they didn't, that would make it an edge case, and I'd write my answer around it :)

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Yeah, accumulator and accessor both begin with acc, so it can definitely throw you off :P

Answer (score -1):

simple filter() for filtering the proper column which has accessor and show values,
and map() to customize the values.

```js
var ƒ = "dummy"
columns = [
           {Header: ƒ, Cell: ƒ, sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "firstName", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "status", sortable: false, show: true},
           {Header: ƒ, accessor: "visits", sortable: false, show: true}
          ]
    
  var finalResult = columns.filter(column => column.accessor && column.show).map(item => {
      return {name: item.accessor,show: item.show}
    })
    
    console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
col.map(element => {
    return {accessor: element.accessor, show: element.show}
})
```

**edit:**
Instead of looping it twice like other solutions, I prefer to loop through it and add only the needed element.

```
let res = [];
columns.forEach(element => {
    if(!!element.accessor) {
        res.push({accessor: element.accessor, show: element.show})
    }
})
```

Comment: This will break for the first item.

Comment: `res` is not defined

Answer (score -2):

You should return object inside the map function

```
columns.map(item => {
   return {name: item.accessor, show: item.show}
});
```

Comment: This will break for the first item.

Comment: If needed you can add a check inside the map